# Is whale meat halal?

Tags: food

In some countries, some people say, that humans eat whale meat is tradition. Is whale meat halal as human food?

Answer (score 3):

> Narrated Abu Hurayrah:
>
> A man asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ): Messenger of Allah, we travel
>   on the sea and take a small quantity of water with us. If we use this
>   for ablution, we would suffer from thirst. Can we perform ablution
>   with sea water? The Messenger (ﷺ) replied: Its water is pure and **what
>   dies in it is lawful food.** 
>   
>  [Sunan Abi Dawud 83](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/1/83)

Allah also says in the Quran:

> **Lawful to you is game from the sea and its food as provision for you
>   and the travelers,** but forbidden to you is game from the land as long
>   as you are in the state of ihram. And fear Allah to whom you will be
>   gathered. [Quran 5:96](https://quran.com/5/96)

Most purely  aquatic life is considered Halal. There is debate on amphibians but w.r.t your question whale is a purely aquatic creature that is considered Halal.

Also look at:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/1919/are-there-any-types-of-seafood-that-muslims-are-not-permitted-to-eat

Comment: [This](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/27) hadith is also relevant.